# Relation of dump.pm2 and ecosystem.json

Tags: pm2

i'm using pm2-windows-service to start PM2 as service.
I don't understand the relationship between dump.pm2 and ecosystem.json. It looks like they are all the pm2 boot config that will be used. But which would take precedence if both in dump.pm2 and ecosystem.json were defined?
Please tell me the answer . Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

ecosystem.json will have a higher priority than dump.pm2.
When there is no ecosystem.json file it will use dump.pm2 file. dump.pm2 will be generated when running the command : pm2 save.

It is more convenient to use the ecosystem.json because we just need to change the settings in the ecosystem.json. If we use dump.pm2, we need to run the app again (pm2 start ...) and then update the dump file with the command : pm2 save